# Get String Between First n Character and Last n Charcter in C#

Tags: c#, string

**My String:** `draw.text("hello",11,22);`

**Need Output:** 11

So i need to get a `String` Between first **,** character and Last **,** character.
Its not duplicate question.I not found same questions.
**I need to get the 2nd argument in my string,the string between first `,` and last `,` in string**

Comment: It's not clear why you've included the linq tag here. But `string.Substring` is almost certainly what you're looking for. (If it's not, please clarify the question - it's unclear at the moment why 11 *should* be the output for your example.)

Comment: Is it always "hello" as your first parameter in the string? Or do you want to substring the second parameters at all times?

Comment: @JonSkeet I need to get string betweeen **First , Character in String** and **Last , Character in String**

Comment: It is still unclear exactly what you're asking, please add some examples of input and desired output to try and clarify your requirements. It might also help to include what you're already tried.

Comment: Please clarify your question to indicate that the comma is intended to be "a specified character". It looks like just punctuation at the moment. This isn't helped by your title that uses "n" - which tends to be used as a placeholder for a number (e.g. the first 5 characters and the last 5 characters). Providing a [mcve] would have clarified the requirements too.

Comment: Do you mean that the string is ***hello, 11, 12*** and then you want to get the string in between the `,` characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your string on the `,` character, remove the first and last item, and join the remaining components back together:

```
var input = "draw.text(\"hello\",11,22);";

var components = input.Split(',');
var result = String.Join(",", components.Skip(1).Take(components.Length - 2)); 
// yields 11
```

Note: `using System.Linq` is required for `Skip` and `Take`.

Comment: It won't work if the first parameter contains a comma in the string literal, but it's what OP is asking for regardless.

Comment: @Adriani6: Indeed. If the OP wants to correctly parse C-style function invocations, he should say so. :-)

Comment: @Heinzi Its work,How to get the last argument in my string?

Comment: I tried to get the last arugment by using my own void,called GetBetween,but its got bad code,so i got `11,22` as last argument

Comment: @Qrai: If you want to get the arguments, I would suggest to (1) remove everything before the first `(`, (2) remove everything after the last `)` and then (3) split on `,`. This will give you an array of all the arguments. If you understood my answer, you should already know how to do (1) and (2) easily (using `String.Split`).

Comment: @Qrai: If you have your own method where you've tried to implement this, it would be *really* helpful to include a [mcve] with that in your question. That would simultaneously a) demonstrate the requirements; b) show what you've tried before asking; c) help us to correct the code rather than invent new code - which may help you fix some understanding issues.